# Property of the derivative of a function

Tags: calculus

A function f has derivative for all $x\in \mathbb R$ and the limits of $f$ at $+\infty $, $-\infty$ are equal to  $+\infty$ . Is it true that $\lim_{x\to a} \frac {1}{f'(x)} = + \infty $ or $-\infty$  for some $a\in\mathbb R$ ?

Of course function $f' $ has roots , according to Fermat's theorem( $f$ has a total infimum) but how I could find an example to prove that the statement is W(wrong), if it really is wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Babis

Comment: We are happy to see you here Mr. Stergiou. This site will be better  with you.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is false. In fact you can take $f$ to be constant in some interval and let $f$ be decreasing before that interval and increasing after that interval. Thus let $f(x) =(x+1)^{2},x<-1,f(x)=0,|x|\leq 1,f(x)=(x-1)^{2},x>1$. Then we can see that $f$ is differentiable everywhere, but there is no point where $1/f'(x) \to \pm\infty$.

Comment: But $f'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to -1$ and so $\frac{1}{f'(x)} \to \infty$ as $x \to -1$.

Comment: The function $1/f'$ is not defined in neighborhood of any point in $[-1,1]$.  One can construct examples where we have $f'$ is positive everywhere except fro a single point where it vanishes and moreover it does not tend to $0$ at the exceptional point.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for(my poor english and ) comig again, I'm new here and I probably I do something in a wrong  way.There was a typo in my first messange and the problem exists yet.

My original question is to find if the function   $\frac {1}{f'(x)}$ has a vertical asymptote.

The function $f' $ has the Darboux property  and I'm trying to prove that the statement is false.But is it really fasle?

So , I'm trying to prove that  there is a function(or to construct  a function) , such that for all points  $a$ which are roots of $f'$ , both limits

$\lim_{x\to a^{+}}\frac {1}{f'(x)}$ ,$\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac {1}{f'(x)}$

are not equal to $+\infty $ or $ -\infty$  or these limits are not defined.